# What's X-style geometry string?

Tags: linux, geometry

I want to use feh in linux to open an image at the specific location.
I used "man feh" , just to find "feh -g " or "feh --geometry".
However, the arguments needed to input is a x-style geometry string.

the format is

```
feh -g width x height [ + x + y ]
```

I just copy the format from "man feh"
x , y are the offsets which I need.
But how to input this?
Could you give me an example ?

Comment: I suppose ``feh -g 128x128+10+20 somefilename`` doesn't open ``somefilename`` at position (10, 20) on your screen with a window size of 128x128 pixels?